# Select values from a table where a text field does not contain a word present in another column

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have a table called COMMENTS that looks like this:

| First Name | Text |
| --- | --- |
| Frankie | Frankie is... |
| Sarah | Sarah is... |
| Graham | Graham is... |

and another table, NAMES, that lists all the names:

| First name |
| --- |
| Frankie |
| Sarah |
| Graham |
| Richard |
| Graham |

I am trying to write a SELECT statement that returns all the rows where the text in 'Text' contains a name from 'First name', which isn't their own.

The issue I have faced so far is that the 'First Name' always returns true because their own name exists in the list of all names.

I'm after a statement that returns when:

If 'Text' contains a name from NAMES that isn't their own return that row.

Is this even possible with SELECT statements?

Comment: Hi, can you elaborate your request a bit? what do you want to do? what is error? and what is desired output?

Comment: Hi... Yes... Thanks... I just want to check that if someone has copied and pasted the comment from one person to another that they have made sure they have changed the name. So if the 'Text' field in the 'COMMENTS' table only refers to the 'First Name' in the same row it does not return any results, but if 'Text' references a name other than that in the same row, it returns that row for checking.

Comment: Does the comment text always contain a name from the NAMES table?

Comment: Please post what you have tried so we may assist you in fixing it; OR visit a site the generates code for you (perhaps for pay....)

Comment: Do you care if `'Lenny'` matches `'Sarah saw a blenny on the reef.'`? `'Bob'` in `'discombobulated'`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This returns comments with all the names in their text, except the commenter's own name:

```
select  *
from    COMMENTS c
join    NAMES n
on      n.FirstName <> c.FirstName
        and c.Text like '%' + n.FirstName '%'
```

Comment: Question: why provide code when the OP appears to not have even made an attempt (or at least posted none?)

Comment: Thanks Andomar, you have been really helpful and the solution works. It was the `n.FirstName <> c.FirstName` I was missing. @MarkSchultheiss Yes, I should have posted my best attempt at getting it to work. Apologies. Your profile reads "Be kind always - you never know what kind of challenges the other person has at any given moment".

Answer (score 1):

Not obvious, but doable:

```
WITH
-- in data - not part of final query ..
comments(First_Name,Text) AS (
          SELECT 'Frankie','Frankie is tall'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Sarah','Sarah is Richard''s friend'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Graham','Graham is taller than Frankie'
)
,
fname(First_name) AS (
          SELECT 'Frankie'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Sarah'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Graham'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Richard'
UNION ALL SELECT 'Graham'
)
-- end of input, real query starts here
-- replace following comma wiht "WITH" ..
SELECT
  comments.*
, fname.first_name as ffname
FROM fname
JOIN comments 
  ON comments.first_name <> fname.first_name
 AND comments.text LIKE '%'||fname.first_name||'%'
;
-- out  First_Name |             Text              | ffname  
-- out ------------+-------------------------------+---------
-- out  Sarah      | Sarah is Richard's friend     | Richard
-- out  Graham     | Graham is taller than Frankie | Frankie
```

Comment: The `values` table constructor is much neater than `select ... union all ...`

Comment: but it's more portable to other DBMS-s ....

Comment: Question is specific to SQL server - so fine to use t-sql.